# Different width on Chrome and Firefox on same screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

recently I find that new version of firefox is show width, significantly different from chrome 
this is my table which show completely different in fire fox and chrome . Is there any idea for this case?

```
           <table id="headtable" class=" tahoma">
             <tr>
              <td width="84">نام سرور</td>
              <td width="62">CPU</td>
              <td width="46">RAM</td>
              <td width="34" class="tool-tip">نوع هارد دیسک </td>
              <td width="79">فضا</td>
              <td width="43" class="tool-tip">پهنای باند </td>
              <td width="46" class="tool-tip">ترافیک ماهیانه </td>
              <td width="59">دیتا سنتر</td>
              <td width="69" class="tool-tip">کنترل پنل </td>
              <td width="47" class="tool-tip">هزینه‌ی راه اندازی </td>
              <td width="54">هزینه‌ی ماهیانه</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       <div class="hole" id="hole">
        <table id="panels-compare" class="tahoma compare panels">
        <tr>
            <td width="66">ایران۷</td>
            <td width="62">Xeon 3430</td>
            <td width="46">۸ گیگابایت</td>
            <td width="58">SATA</td>
            <td width="81">2x500GB</td>
            <td width="43">۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
            <td width="46">۱۰۰ گیگابایت</td>
            <td width="59">پارس‌آنلاین / افرانت</td>
            <td width="69">DirectAdmin</td>
            <td width="46">۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td width="54">۳۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td width="">سفارش</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>
```

[image: screenshot of chrome]
[image: screenshot of firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Weird. That can't be the code for the image as displayed, so I'm going to take a guess... Maybe you missed a column, it looks like some are the same size and others are not. Or, maybe the sum of the td widths is greater than one if its containing elements, and the browsers are responding to the invalid state differently. Similarly, it may be that invalid html elsewhere on the page is behind this - if all else fails, ensure your markup is valid.

Comment: It looks like one is missing a width, I wonder if this would be enough to freak out one of the browsers...

Comment: I give standard size to that one in css becusea that one is special in my layout.

Comment: Ahh, right on - it looks like the two tables don't have the same width, I wonder if that has anything to do with it. Also, is there any reason not to just use <th>s?

Comment: maybe I use css hacks but because I style this part inline I cant even use css hacks :|, no not special reason.

Comment: I don't think it should come to that, I'm guessing the solution is frustratingly simple. I wonder if just specifying that blank width is messing it up somehow, too, as a possibility.

Comment: u can see this tow table is different from each other, table 2 have 1 more column, yes and these 2 tables dont have same width, and now I test it I full the blank part with inline width but still same problem occur

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the "clutter" a browser has.

Google chrome has "clean" UI, it doesn't take up too much space for its address bar, bookmark bar etc..

Whereas Mozilla too has its own way of displaying things.

So there is no standard that defines how much screen a browser should use for address bar, bookmarks bar, home button, back-front buttons, tabs etc..

So just leave it as there is not much you can do other than what you've already done to have a uniform size.

Comment: Other than to specifically specify said size in pixels, which has been done here...

Comment: I wondered about the browser elements and available width, too, but there shouldn't be anything special here - one might expect it to scroll horizontally, unless specifically told not to. If it were a 500px image, it would never draw at 495px in one, due to width constraints...

Comment: @AmitJoki I have same page like this but I dont have same problem with "width".